# WPF toplevel MenuItem enable/disable based on task

Tags: wpf, click, menuitem

I have a top-level menu item which is responsible for refreshing a datagrid in the same window. My current control flow is:

1. User clicks on refresh
2. In the click event handler, I:

   1. Disable the menuitem, by setting `oMenuItem.IsEnabled = false`.
   2. Dispatch an action to refresh the grid and in that action, I re-enable the menuitem, by setting `IsEnabled = true`

The problem is that the user can click refresh even when it's disabled and it's as if the clicks get queued up. When the action returns it goes on to process the remaining, "queued-up" clicks. What I expect is: all clicks while the menuitem is disabled are ignored and only when it's enabled, the clicks are acknowledged.

The weird thing is that if I just disable it and never enable it it stays that way, i.e., it is disabled.wpf,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dispatch an action" you mean by calling Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() or some other kind of async opetation?

Anyway, in both cases you can get a "handle" to the operation (DispatcherOperation or IAsyncResult) and store it as a field when you dispatch your operation. When it completes - set this field to null.

In the click event handler of the menu-item check this field. If it's null it means it is safe to start the operation. If it is not null - return immediately and do nothing.

And something not related to your question but important - why not use Commands? That way you don't need to play with event handling and enabling/disabling. And of course commands can be invoked by multiple means (for example - the user selected the command from the menu using the keyboard and pressed Enter. No mouse clicks involved, but should do the same as clicking the menu item).

Alex.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the response. I did go with the Command way too, and in my CanExecute handler checked if the MenuItem's IsEnabled property was false; essentially, e.CanExecute = oMenuItem.IsEnabled. This had the same behavior with my previous non-IAsyncResult approach. I'm going to give your approach a shot, and hopefully get this figured out.

Comment: The thing with commands is that you can put them inside a ViewModel and thus seperate presentation from logic. Google MVVM if you don't know what I am talking about.
(In short - it allows you to test your logic as a simple class without requiring to display a window with all the controls).

Anyway, in case you go with MVVM, the IAsyncResult field should be stored in the ViewModel and not in the view.